# Live Search using Ajax and Getting Error "500 (Internal Server Error)" on Laravel 5.8

Tags: ajax, laravel

I was following tutorial to Live Search using ajax on Laravel, but in the implementation I get **error**:

> GET http://localhost:8000/search?search=k 500 (Internal Server Error)

I was following this tutorial 3 times but always getthis same error. I modified like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta name="_token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}"> 
        <title>Live Search</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="panel panel-default">
                    <div class="panel-heading">
                        <h3>Products info </h3>
                    </div>
                    <div class="panel-body">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <input type="text" class="form-controller" id="search" name="search">
                            <input type="hidden" name="_method" value="POST">
                            <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">
                        </div>
                        <table class="table table-bordered table-hover">
                            <thead>
                                <tr>
                                  <th>ID</th>
                                  <th>Product Name</th>
                                  <th>Description</th>
                                  <th>Price</th>
                                </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody>
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <script type="text/javascript">
            $('#search').on('keyup',function() {
                $value=$(this).val();
                $.ajax({
                    type : 'get',
                    url : '{{URL::to('search')}}',
                    data:{'search':$value},
                    success:function(data){
                        $('tbody').html(data);
                    }
                });
            });
        </script>

        <script type="text/javascript">
            $.ajaxSetup({ headers: { 'csrftoken' : '{{ csrf_token() }}' } });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

**my controller:**

```
public function search(Request $request)
{
    if($request->ajax()) {
        $output="";
        $products=DB::table('products')->where('title','LIKE','%'.$request->search."%")->get();
        if($products) {
            foreach ($products as $key => $product) {
                $output.='<tr>'.
                  '<td>'.$product->id.'</td>'.
                  '<td>'.$product->title.'</td>'.
                  '<td>'.$product->description.'</td>'.
                  '<td>'.$product->price.'</td>'.
                '</tr>';
            }
            return Response($output);
        }
    }
}
```

I was trying this code for 3 different database and always get the same error 500 .

Comment: I would suggest setting up debugging on your IDE so that you can drill into exactly what is going on with your code. What do you use to write your code?

Comment: i using visual studio code . and i running this not getting error

Comment: Yeah, if you don't have it set up already I would highly recommend it - see this link for more details: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/debugging .

Comment: @AdhikMulat, can You show all `error`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to `declare variable` in `Jquery/Javascript` like below :

```
 var value=$(this).val();
```

and pass this `variable` like below in `ajax` :

```
data:{'search':value}
```

Change above lines ,it should work !

Answer (score 1):

You have call `ajax` using `get` method, so first check your route file.

I think you are calling `search` method using post method.

Also in ajax code default is get method

you have to specify : `method : post`